# What is the meaning of this icon in Xcode 7 debug navigator?

Tags: xcode, xcode7

[image: Bright lights are on icon?] This icon appears beside my program name in the debug navigator when running in the debugger in Xcode 7. I think it's new. I assume it means my lights are on. I checked, though, and they're off. Any other ideas?

Comment: Does it not have a tooltip when you mouse hover over it for a moment?  The other icons in the debug bar seem to.  My app does not have such an icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indicates an open crash report. If you open a crash report from the Organizer, it opens in the debug view and shows you the running threads and stack status from the crash report. I forgot I had one open. There's no way to close it that I can find.

Answer (score 0):

Apple documented it in the Process View Display section.

> image:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH8-SW19

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the crash report from the debug navigator by selecting the item and hitting backspace (←). This works actually with Xcode 11.5.